# Google blocking my account for login outside my country

Tags: android, gmail

In my Android application I am using Gmail library to send mail from android application for password reset. (Since my app is distributed on play store)when My app is used out side my country (say Us), Google is blocking my account as suspicious Login. How can I solve this problem

Comment: ask to google support team dude.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about coding

Comment: Don't send mail from your app but from your backend. Don't distribute your gmail credentials with your app.